# Problems with PHP member search

Tags: php, forms

I am still pretty new to PHP so forgive me if I am overlooking something easy. I am trying to build a member search form that allows people to find a member by entering one or more criteria: first name or username, city, state, country, or by email address. The form works if a single field is entered, or multiple fields ONLY when the name/username field has a value. Assuming it's a logic issue. Thanks in advance.

```
if (!isset($_POST['fname']))
{
//If not isset -> set with dummy value
$_POST['fname'] = "undefine";
} 
if (!isset($_POST['city']))
{
//If not isset -> set with dummy value
$_POST['city'] = "undefine";
} 
if (!isset($_POST['state']))
{
//If not isset -> set with dummy value
$_POST['state'] = "undefine";
} 
if (!isset($_POST['country']))
{
//If not isset -> set with dummy value
$_POST['country'] = "undefine";
} 
if (!isset($_POST['email']))
{
//If not isset -> set with dummy value
$_POST['email'] = "undefine";
} 

// DEFAULT QUERY STRING
$queryString = '';

if ($_POST['fname'] != '') {
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $fname = stripslashes($fname); 
  $fname = strip_tags($fname);
  $fname = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z 0-9]#i', '', $fname);
  $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
  $queryString = "(firstname LIKE '%$fname%' OR username LIKE '%$fname%')";
} else {
  $queryString = '';
} 

if ($_POST['city'] != '') {

    if (($_POST['fname'] != '') || ($_POST['state'] != '') || ($_POST['country'] != '') || ($_POST['email'] != '')){
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $city = stripslashes($city); 
        $city = strip_tags($city);
        $city = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z 0-9]#i', '', $city);
        $city = mysql_real_escape_string($city);
      $queryString .= " AND city='$city'";
    }  else {
  $city = $_POST['city'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $city = stripslashes($city); 
        $city = strip_tags($city);
        $city = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z 0-9]#i', '', $city);
        $city = mysql_real_escape_string($city);
  $queryString .= "city='$city'";
  } 
  } else {
  $queryString .= '';
}   

if ($_POST['state'] != '') {

    if (($_POST['fname']) || ($_POST['city']) || ($_POST['country']) || ($_POST['email'])){
      $state = $_POST['state'];
        $state = stripslashes($state); 
        $state = strip_tags($state);
        $state = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z 0-9]#i', '', $state);
        $state = mysql_real_escape_string($state);
      $queryString .= " AND state='$state'";
    }  else {
  $state = $_POST['state'];
        $state = stripslashes($state); 
        $state = strip_tags($state);
        $state = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z 0-9]#i', '', $state);
        $state = mysql_real_escape_string($state);
  $queryString .= "state='$state'";
  } 
  } else {
  $queryString .= '';
}   

if ($_POST['country'] != '') {

    if (($_POST['fname']) || ($_POST['city']) || ($_POST['state']) || ($_POST['email'])) {
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $queryString .= " AND country='$country'";
  }
  else {
  $country = $_POST['country'];
  $queryString .= "country='$country'";
  }
} else {
  $queryString .= '';
}   

if ($_POST['email'] != '') {

    if (($_POST['fname']) || ($_POST['city']) || ($_POST['state']) || ($_POST['country'])){
      $email = $_POST['email'];
                $email = stripslashes($email); 
        $email = strip_tags($email);
        $email = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z 0-9,.@-]#i', '', $email);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
      $queryString .= " AND email='$email'";
    }  else {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $queryString .= "email='$email'";
  } 
  } else {
  $queryString .= '';
}   

//////////////  QUERY THE MEMBER DATA USING THE $queryString variable's value
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, firstname, city, state, country FROM members WHERE $queryString AND emailactivated='1' ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// get all posted data like this

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']))
{
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
}
```

//get all field values

```
if(empty($fname))
{
}
else
{
     $where . ="fname=$fname and ";
}  
//Check and build where for each field 

//  then remove the last and 

$where  = rtrim($where, ' AND ');

if (empty($where)) {
         $where_str = NULL;
      } else {
         $where_str = "WHERE $where";
      } 

$query ="select fieldNames from tableName ";

$query . =$where_str;
```

Comment: This did the trick! FYI: I had to change "and" to "AND" and the concatenation formatting from `. =` to `.=` to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a VERY hideous method to build the query string. I'd say scrap it and start over, but since you're new, we'll just work with what you've got.

First step is to stop assuming your SQL is working. You don't have any error checking on your query call, so you get ZERO in the way of useful feedback. So change the query call to:

```
$sql = mysql_query(...query...) or die(mysql_error()); 
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---add this
```

Now you'll get a nice dump of the actual mysql error message, along with a snippet of the query to explain where/how the query's wrong. Most likely, given all those fields you're adding in there, you've forgotten a space or something and make the query look something like `p=qand z=y` (note the lack of a space between the `q` and `and`).

Once you get those error messages, you'll have a much easier time figuring out where the syntax error is, and what's needed to fix it.

Comment: I added the or die statement and got this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND city='Denver' AND country='United States' AND emailactivated='1' ORDER BY id' at line 1

Comment: The snippet looks ok, most likely the error is IMMEDIATELY before the `AND city` bit, so you'll have to dump out the whole query string and check that out.

Comment: Oh, and before I forget... kudos for using mysql_real_escape_string() in all that. You would not BELIEVE how many PHP beginners don't ever bother preventing sql injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks! I have read questions on here enough to see SQL injection prevention mentioned over and over. I felt it was important to make it a habit. Regarding the "dumping the whole query string" - can you clarify?

Comment: build your query into a string, e.g. `$sql = "SELECT ..."; mysql_query($sql);` etc... now you've got the full query in a variable, and can simply echo it out to see the entire thing.

Comment: I think the issue is that if $fname is blank, $Querystring will begin with 'AND' right after 'WHERE' in the query. I will have to attack this again with a clear head in the morning.

Comment: I'd suggest simply adding the conditions to an array, e.g. `$condition[] = "somefield=$somevalue"`, then do an `$wheres = implode(' AND ', $condition)`, which'll put in the proper number of ands, and save you all of that `if()` business.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems I see:

1. In your `isset` tests, you set undefined variables to `'undefine'`, but when you create your queries, you test for `''`. This means if the name is blank, you'll always be looking for someone named `undefine`.
2. You should not be attempting to modify `$_POST` variables with your code. You need to load `$_POST` into another variable and work with that in your code.

Comment: You're right... I actually got the 'undefine' solution from somewhere for a different error I was getting at the time. I changed the `!isset = 'undefine'` part to instead initialize the variables if the field was set by the form. Still getting my initial error though